# Angular UI-Router Best Practices: Share Data Between named views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm migrating from angular-route to ui-router and Im trying to figure out what is the best option for build the following scenario:

I have a generic panel wich is composed of two nested elements showed at the same time: A **FORM**(rendered on the left) and a simple **LIST** (rendered on the right).

The **form** is used to edit or even create a new item for the list (this manipulation is made throught a service makes ajax calls)

The **list** shows all items and I can select one of them and click on "edit", after that the item goes to the form and I'll be able to manipulate/update it.

Here is my code:

```
     .state('mt.demos', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/demos',
            views : {
                    'container@' : {
                    templateUrl: '....demos.html'
                }
            }
        })

     .state('mt.panel', {
            url: '',
            views: {
                'form@mt.demos': {
                    templateUrl: '...form.html',
                    controller : 'formController',
                    controllerAs : 'vm', 
                },
                'list@mt.demos': {
                    templateUrl: '...list.html',
                    controller : 'listController',
                    controllerAs : 'vm',

                }
            }
        })
```

So far I ended up with those 2 options:

1. Create a service for the shared data (this seems to be the most acceptable answer due to its Singleton behavior -- but look the **NOTE 1** at the end of this post.
2. Create a parent controller so each nested state can access parent properts like the list or the item to be edited. So when I click on "edit item" the listController updates the parent's scope and the  formController will be changed with this data.

**NOTE 1:**  Of course to retrieve the list and to update items I already use one service called demoService. This service is used for ajax requests only. So If the best decision is the options 1 showed above, I belive that I should create a new service with a new proposal, right? Or it isnt bad to store some local variable in this same service.
This new service will have the list and the item itself, so when I click on edit I will update the service "item" property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already have an answer of using a service to store your data.

About a new service with new proposal, while I'm not entirely sure what a 'proposal' means, I'm assuming you are referring to a different list with different fields with your current one?

In that case that would depends on how reusable your code is. If your forms are similar enough, or you can generalize it, then it might be fine to share the same service so you don't have to rewrite the functions. The lists and selected items can be stored as different variables in the service.

Or, you can also store them in different service, and write their common functions in another service.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! ;)   The new "proposal" is just to point that all my files called xxxService are used only to communicate with the server. I had never used these files to store shared data between different controllers. So returning to the question, my service called demoService is used in other parts of my apllication and the shared data (list and item) will be used only by the listController and itemController. So, others controllers that will call demoService will be not using this shared data (they only use it to retrieve data from server).

Comment: I think it should be different service then, list and item in one, and the ajax in another one. The list service can call the ajax service when they need to get data as well. From my personal experience, though, storing all different ajax url in one file is not a good idea, it will grow until it is pointless someday. I found it cleaner to keep in their respective service.

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up doing a new service to share the data and treat some forms issues. Thank you for your help